# how to run commands after ' kubectl run image command' in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to run ' **apt update**' and ' **apt install mysql-server**' after Kubernetes run command:

```
kubectl run -i --tty ubuntu1 --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -- bash
```

need to add `apt update` & `apt install mysql-server` along the above cmd.

Comment: You probably need to build a custom Docker image, push it to a registry, and refer to that in your Kubernetes manifests.  In the case of a database image, there are prebuilt images, Helm charts, and Kubernetes operators, all of which can do this for you.  Manually installing software in a container like this will cause you to lose work if the pod is ever deleted, and there are common circumstances where Kubernetes automatically deletes pod without asking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl run -it ubuntu1 --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -- bash -c "apt update; apt install mysql-server; bash"`